# SQL error: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x00

Tags: regex, perl, sed

I am running an SQL program and I get this error

```
CONTEXT:  COPY qc_v1_ships_1854, line 6383 at load_QC_tables.pl line 86.
DBD::Pg::db do failed: ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x00
```

when I look at the file I am trying to upload to the data base the problematic line has a `<nul>` character

```
   465490013905000000 | NIGHTING_2_SAM<nul> |    5 |    3 |   -1 |    1
```

which I think is the problem. However when I run

```
sed -i 's/\0x00/ /g' *.dat
```

nothing change. Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a `sed` regex pattern, `\0` is the as just `0`. You want

```
sed -i 's/\x00/ /g' *.dat
```

Or since you're using Perl already, the Perl equivalent is

```
perl -i -pe's/\x00/ /g' *.dat
```

Faster:

```
perl -i -pe'tr/\x00/ /' *.dat
```

Comment: `s/\x00/ /g` and `tr/\x00//d` are not equivalent, one deletes and one replaces with space.

Comment: @TLP, Oops, thought he was removing them. Fixed